# NoMethodError when passing path to rails partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, path, partial-views

I have 3 models that share this similar form to submit votes. This form in included in each of the models show page so I would like to put this code into a partial to clean everything up.

**questions/show.html.erb**

```
<div class="vote">
    <div id="questions">
      <h1><%= @question.votes_count %></h1>
    </div>
    <%= link_to "up", vote_question_path(@question, value: 1), remote: true, method: "post" %>
    <%= link_to "down", vote_question_path(@question, value: -1),remote: true, method: "post" %>
</div>
```

I have tried moving this code into a partial as per the code below:

**vote/_form.html.erb**

```
<div class="vote">
    <div id="votes_count">
        Votes: <%= object.votes_count %>
    </div>
    <%= link_to "up", vote_path(object, value: 1),remote: true, method: "post" %>
    <%= link_to "down", vote_path(answer, value: -1), remote: true,  method: "post" %>
</div>
```

I replace the previous code in the show pages with the following call to render the partial:

```
<%= render partial: "votes/form", locals: {object: @question, vote_path: answer_question_path } %>
```

However, with trying various string methods and also the send(path) method to pass the vote_question_path into the partial it always errors out `with NoMethodError undefined method "vote_path"`.

How can i correctly and cleanly pass these paths into this particular partial?

*If anyone needs more code just shout.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doing things your way, Rails tries to evaluate the path right away, thus failing. However, depending on your Ruby version, you may try to pass the method object directly, like that :

```
<%= render partial: "votes/form", locals: {object: @question, vote_path: method(:answer_question_path) } %>
```

then, in vote/_form

```
<div class="vote">
    <div id="votes_count">
        Votes: <%= object.votes_count %>
    </div>
    <%= link_to "up", vote_path.call(object, value: 1), remote: true, method: "post" %>
    <%= link_to "down", vote_path.call(object, value: -1), remote: true,  method: "post" %>
</div>
```

Please see : http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-method

Comment: Thank you for the answers christianblais & zolter, for the record both solutions work perfectly, I'm going to mark christianblais answers as correct just because there is simply less code in the view. If anyone has any suggestions about which would be considered more of a best practice it would be gladly received.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
<%= render partial: "votes/form", locals: {object: @question, up_vote_path: vote_question_path(@question, value: 1), down_vote_path: vote_question_path(@question, value: -1) }  %>
```

**vote/_form**

```
<div class="vote">
    <div id="votes_count">
        Votes: <%= object.votes_count %>
    </div>
    <%= link_to "up", up_vote_path,remote: true, method: "post" %>
    <%= link_to "down", down_vote_path, remote: true,  method: "post" %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case you can use either approach outlined in the previous comments. However, there is a slight difference between the 2 approaches.

Let's assume that someone has this code (this is your case also)

**questions/show.html.erb**

```
<div class="vote">
    <div id="questions">
      <h1><%= @question.votes_count %></h1>
    </div>
    <%= link_to "up", vote_question_path(@question, value: 1), remote: true, method: "post" %>
    <%= link_to "down", vote_question_path(@question, value: -1),remote: true, method: "post" %>
</div>
```

In this case the following partial will work fine:

```
<%= render partial: "votes/form", locals: {object: @question, up_vote_path: vote_question_path(@question, value: 1), down_vote_path: vote_question_path(@question, value: -1) }  %>
```

However, if we assume that someone has this code instead (someone has to iterate through a collection):

**questions/show.html.erb**

```
<% @users.each do | user | %>
  <div class="vote">
      <div id="questions">
        <h1><%= @question.votes_count %></h1>
      </div>
      <%= link_to "up", vote_question_path(user, @question, value: 1), remote: true, method: "post" %>
      <%= link_to "down", vote_question_path(user, @question, value: -1), remote: true,  method: "post" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

than this approach is not going to work, because there is no way to get those collection items at the place of rendering. In this case the `vote_path: method(:answer_question_path)` is better.